# How long is a Stripe Checkout session valid for?

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

I'm creating a Stripe Checkout session via the C# SDK and wish to know how long the session will be valid for.

```
var options = new SessionCreateOptions
  {
    SuccessUrl = "https://example.com/success.html?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",
    CancelUrl = "https://example.com/canceled.html",
    PaymentMethodTypes = new List<string>
    {
      "card",
    },
    Mode = "subscription",
    LineItems = new List<SessionLineItemOptions>
    {
      new SessionLineItemOptions
      {
        Price = req.PriceId,
        Quantity = 1,
      },
    },
  };

  var service = new SessionService();
  var session = await service.CreateAsync(options);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stripe Checkout Sessions expire 24 hours after creation.

Source: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment